# trying to setup TinyWebDB on google cloud, but deploy not working

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-inventor

I am trying to follow the instructions on [this page](https://sites.google.com/a/wellesley.edu/wellesley-cs117-fall14/goodies/tinywebdb-services/creating-a-custom-tinywebdb-service), and they are working great, until the part where I deploy from my Google App Engine Launcher. When I click deploy I should see something like this:
[image]

But instead, I see something like this:
[image]

and the end result is that my app doesn't get deployed to xxxxxxx.appspot.com, it redirects me to http://localhost:8080/?code=4/EfmizPdAPVDgoSInA8mS1KVOvQTkWX4ziFnEpG3XKxA#

I'm a begginer with this kind of tech, please, any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: use the latest instructions, which you can find [here](https://sites.google.com/a/wellesley.edu/wellesley-cs117-fall15/how-tos/how-to-use-and-create-specialized-web-services/creating-a-custom-tinywebdb-service) and in case these do not help, ask the author in the [App Inventor Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest)...

Comment: Gracias mi pana. Oye y para no seguir preguntando huevadas, habra alguna lista actualizada donde pueda ver los ultimos tutorials?

Comment: A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles

Comment: Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Thanks @Taifun, I followed the new instructions and had the same problem, the deploy fails with `--noauth_local_webserver`. I'll ask in the Forum. Thanks for the extra links, I have already developed an app... it was super easy! I just want to be able to create a webserver, but it doesn't work. Let's see if anyone saw my bug there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here. In my case, what worked was to first disable the app in the App Engine Launcher, and *only then* hit deploy. First time I tried, it authenticated, then second time I deployed, it deployed successfully. Thanks Arnie.

In case, I post his other suggestions:

1) remember to give your google id access to less secure apps.

2) remember to go to appspot.com or https://appengine.google.com/ and accept terms and conditions. Your project should also be active on https://console.developers.google.com/project

3) use correct versions of python and google app engine SDK

4) Before hitting deploy button on google app engine stop the app from running on your local host. It will NOT deploy while it is running locally on local host.